# Are questions about bugs that help players on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'd like to ask what bugs there are in a game that help players, but I can easily see this becoming a "list" question (albeit a limited one).

For example, I have just seen in *Civilization 4* that your trading partners may refuse to trade an item with you (if you ask, "What will make this work?" and they reply, "I can't see how this will work" (i.e. nothing)) but if you then ask them to spare it "for a friend" they sometimes reply, "always happen to help" and give it to you **for free**.

Is it appropriate, then, to ask, "What bugs are there in [Civilization 4] that help players?"

I hope so, because I can see this being a *really* useful question!

Answer (score 3):

Questions about bugs are fine; we have plenty of question about minecart boosters.

Asking for a list of bugs is a much iffier proposition. I'd try coming up with some items to start a CW answer with, encouraging others to add to it... but then again, this is something that fits a Civ4 wiki much better if you ask me.

Comment: so my specific example is definitely **off topic**?

Comment: @Wikis I'd side with that thought, yes. Remember, the ultimate goal is that answers should *solve* the question on their own right. If you just ask for "bugs that help players in Civ4", most answers will bring up single bugs, and individually none of that solves your question. It's different than how, say, asking for a list of in-game items typically plays out (in which one user tends to provide the full list in one answer).

Comment: How does that differ from [General strategies/build order in Civilization 5](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8769/general-strategies-build-order-in-civilization-5)? Both don't appear to have specific answers. I'll accept this, of course, but it seems a shame because the question could generate some useful answers.

Comment: @Wikis That's a very good point; as you've seen however the top answer is "it depends", rather than a list of strategies  :)

Comment: thanks. I don't want to go on and on with this so I'll make this the last point: is there any way this type of question *can work*? Or should it simply be, "Is there any site that provides a list of useful "bugs" in Civ4?" But that sounds unintentionally sarcastic! =:-)